# Get notification from Keycloak via API when a new user disabled

Tags: keycloak

We use Keycloak in our project and it became necessary to receive a notification to our service from Keycloak if the user has become disabled. Is it possible? If yes, I would be grateful for an example.
Thanks in advance

UPDATE

Brute force detection

[image]

[image]

my events [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Get [Events API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/18.0/rest-api/#_realmeventsconfigrepresentation)

In `Get the top-level representation of the realm It will not include nested information like User and Client representations` section.

```
GET /{realm}/events
```

[image]

It can be filter by event types, client, date, user, number of events.

You can see the events more detail in [here](https://wjw465150.gitbooks.io/keycloak-documentation/content/server_admin/topics/events/login.html)

The disabled user is this condition.

> type is `LOGIN_ERROR`
>
> error is `user_disabled`

This is example of disabled user data.

```
[
  {
    "time": 1671723235619,
    "type": "LOGIN_ERROR",
    "realmId": "e78f0c77-b44b-48da-850b-9d157e24a439",
    "clientId": "account-console",
    "userId": "417a6295-08b4-4bcc-86a8-ce2c1f158ede",
    "ipAddress": "172.28.0.1",
    "error": "user_disabled",
    "details": {
      "auth_method": "openid-connect",
      "auth_type": "code",
      "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/example/account/#/security/signingin",
      "code_id": "f5d403eb-7aa5-433e-a590-c2d6cd2b872f",
      "username": "user1"
    }
  }
]
```

UI setting

[image]

Express demo
check event and filtered only display  `disabled user`

This URL and parameter

```
http://localhost:3000/user-check?error_type=user_disabled
```

express source code

```js
const axios = require("axios")
const express = require('express')
const config = require('./config.json')
const app = express()

async function checkUser(token, error_type) {
    try {
        const siteUrl = `http://localhost:${config.KEYCLOAK_PORT}/auth/admin/realms/${config.REALM_NAME}/events?first=0&max=10&type=LOGIN_ERROR`
        const response = await axios.get(
            siteUrl,
            {
                headers: {
                    'Accept-Encoding': 'application/json',
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
                }
            }
        );
        const filteredData = (error_type == null) ? response.data :  response.data.filter((el) => el.error === error_type)
        return Promise.resolve(filteredData);

    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
}


async function getToken() {
    try {
        const siteUrl = `http://localhost:${config.KEYCLOAK_PORT}/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token`
        const response = await axios.post(
            siteUrl,
            new URLSearchParams({
                'client_id': 'admin-cli',
                'username': `${config.MASTER_USERNAME}`,
                'password': `${config.MASTER_PASSWORD}`,
                'grant_type': 'password'
            })
        );
        return Promise.resolve(response.data.access_token);
    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
}

app.get('/user-check', async (req, res) => {
    getToken()
        .then((token) => {
            checkUser(token, req.query.error_type)
                .then((results) => {
                    console.log(results.length)
                    res.json(results)
                })
                .catch(error => console.log(error));
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
});
    
app.listen(`${config.EXPRESS_PORT}`, () => console.log(`server running on PORT ${config.EXPRESS_PORT}`))
```

config.json file

```
{
    "MASTER_USERNAME": "admin",
    "MASTER_PASSWORD": "admin",
    "REALM_NAME" : "example",
    "EXPRESS_PORT" : 3000,
    "KEYCLOAK_PORT" : 8080
}
```

This access URL result

```
http://localhost:3000/user-check?error_type=user_disabled
```

If call URL without `error_type`, will shows all of LOGIN_ERROR

```
http://localhost:3000/user-check
```

[image]

This is UI. it shows all of events
The express shows only red box event.

You can apply your notification from this idea.

[image]

##### Update UI with v19.0.3

---

Event Listeners
[image]

User events configuration

[image]

Brute force detection

[image]

Events view

[image]

Disabled User

[image]

##### Update with version 20.0.0

---

Refresh Keyclock UI Screen every fail login
[image]

[image]

[image]

Brute force detection
[image]

Server Version
[image]

User login by Impersonate
[image]

Comment: Hi, i faced that it does not work properly. I wanna disable user when password was entered 5 time wrong. What i see - i see how user blocked in Keycloak in the fifth time, but dont see user_disabled error, i can see Invalid user credentials. when i try again i see event with user_disabled error. It means that user should try one time more.

Comment: @СамирШахмурадлы, No the tip of help for Max login failures "How many failures before wait is triggered." I checked 5 times faille with wrong password. It makes disabled the user immediately.

Comment: yes, user is blocking, but can you see user_disabled error event when you made 5 time wrong password?

Comment: Because I set the `Max login failures` is 5.

Comment: i made the same and i see user_disabled only on the sixth time

Comment: Which Keycloak version using it now? I try it when I return home.

Comment: version is 20.0.0

Comment: could you please check Brute force detection what i added above?

Comment: i also added events screen

Comment: I tested with 20.0.0 but same result. It  means User disabled at 5 times failed.
I did refresh Keyclock UI Screen every fail login. And user login by Impersonate. Can you try as same as my configuration?

Comment: could you see my events screen?

Comment: in my case user also disabled at 5 times, but i can see user_disabled only at 6 time

Comment: i made the same what you did

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253898/discussion-between---and-bench-vue).

Comment: I connected discussion chat now

Comment: Yes, refresh Browser the Keycloak UI side when every failed