# How to subscribe to keycloak events?

Tags: java, keycloak

I should implement user_temporarily_disabled handling in my local service. For example, a user entered the password incorrectly 10 times, in keycloak, this user becomes DISABLED. In this case, I need to do some logic on the side of our service. Is it possible to subscribe to notifications from Keycloak and process them? I don’t want to make a request to keycloak every 20 minutes (for example) to receive events. I want to receive events from keycloak as soon as they arise. could you provide example in java please? thanks in advance

Comment: Client can't subscribe, have to call Event APIs. Similar question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74889050/get-notification-from-keycloak-via-api-when-a-new-user-disabled/74891563#74891563)

Comment: i have new question :-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75596973/disable-users-account-after-a-configurable-period-of-inactivity

Comment: I think there are no solution for automatically block if user has not login last 50 days. I just know time expired policy is possible to deny to access client's resource. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75468760/how-to-get-the-password-expired-date-of-a-user-in-keycloak/75552224#75552224) is my answer. It shows how to handle user limited access a resource by time period.

Comment: I ran into using an event listener. Is it possible to add an attribute and then get the users by filtering on the last_login(configurable) attribute?

https://github.com/ThoreKr/keycloak-last-login-event-listener

Comment: It seems SPI method as .jar. It is not API call method. I don't how a `last_login` of attribute in that listener. In the [`GET /{realm}/events`](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/18.0/rest-api/index.html) API, can filter by user id, ream name, client name, data from, date to, event types and ip address. I have no experience SPI method.

Comment: Hii, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75715668/user-enabled-after-permanent-disabling-in-keycloak