# Disable users account after a configurable period of inactivity

Tags: java, keycloak

Is it possible to block an inactive user after a certain number of days? For example, if a user hasn't been logged in for 50 days, Keycloak automatically blocks them.

If this is possible, will it be possible to read these events through events?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this functionality is not available from the box, but there was activity regarding this:

- https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-5865
- https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/11800

and you need to implement this by yourself.
To do that, you should create a service, job, script, etc, that would use Keycloak's admin REST API to perform that job. Just do the following:

- create a client in the needed realm (if you have many realms, just make it configurable) and assign it roles: manage-users, view-users
- get a token for this client using client_credentials grant type flow
- call admin REST API (https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/15.0/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource). Check the user's last login time and update its representation (block user) if it is required.

Comment: Hi, 'Check the user's last login time' where is this information available?

Comment: We made own authenticator, which save it.