# User enabled after permanent disabling in keycloak

Tags: keycloak

[image]

Hi, i am using permanent lockout after 5 times wrong password entering. We can see user_temporarily_disabled in events, but in some time(about 1-2 minutes) i see that user can login and he is not blocked. What is the problem? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/17604
Decreasing Quick Login Check Milli Seconds solved the problem. User was blocked by quick login, not by 5 time wrong password